# Measure of 2D "Cantor Set" is 0?

Tags: measure-theory

*The Lebesgue measure of a Cantor Set is 0*. But I've been thinking about a problem...does the same result stand if we "extend" this to 2-dimensions?

Just to clarify, If we had a $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ plane, then define $C_n$ as the set that has the middle $3^{rd}$ strip removed of height 1 and width $1/3$, from each of
the intervals from $C_{n−1}$, i.e.

$$ C_0 = [0,1]\times[0,1],$$
$$C_1 = \left(\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]\times\left[0,1\right]\right) \cap \left(\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right]\times\left[0,1\right] \right)...$$

and so on... my thinking is that the measure of the $k^{th}$ removed strip is $(1/3^k)^2,$ therefore, the total measure of $C_n$ is

$$ 1- \sum_k 8^{k-1}\times(1/3^k)^2 = 0.$$

Does this seem right?

**NOTE** Perhaps this is not an extension of Cantor Set in 2 dimensions actually because we keep the y-plane the same

Comment: More common generalisations of the Cantor set to two dimensions is either removing a cross, leaving four corner squares where you repeat (giving you so-called Cantor dust), or removing just the center $\frac13\times\frac13$ square, giving you eight remaining (touching) squares where you repeat (giving you the Sierpinski carpet). They both have measure zero. In even higher dimensions you can mix and match these two and get many different fractals.

Comment: Small comment: the Cantor sets in @Arthur comment both have lebesgue measure zero, but their Hausdorff dimensions are respectively $\ln(2)/\ln(3)$ and $\ln(8)/\ln(9)$, and their Hausdorff measure is strictly positive and finite (I think it's 1 in both cases). Note that the "removing cross" generalization of the Cantor set in $[0,1]^n$, which is ultimately the cartesian product of $n$ copies of the original Cantor set) has always the same Hausdorff dimension ($\ln(2)/\ln(3)$) independently of $n$

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Note that "Removing cross" can generalize in at least 2 very distinct ways: Remove all but the corners, and remove the center cuboid and all cuboids that share a facet. I think you were referring to the "Remove all but the corners" variation.

Comment: @Arthur yes you are right, thanks. I was thinking about "remove all but the corners"

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. Note also that your set is basically the cartesian product between the usual Cantor set and the interval $[0,1]$ (both Lebesgue measurable), and the measure will thus be the product of the measures of these two sets (that is zero).

Same thing if you take the cartesian product of two Cantor sets.

Edit: note, though, that the size of the strips that you remove is $1/3^k$, not $(1/3^k)^2$.